# Is there a function to return the size of a multi_index table?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

Is there a function to return the size of a multi_index table?  If not is there a better way then looping through them?

`uint64_t count;
for (auto itr = table.begin(); itr != table.end(); ++itr) {
    ++count;
}`

Answer (score 4):

Agree no size is maintained by EOS implementation , the iterators are not random access , so if size state not maintained (which would be best performance compared to calculating size on the fly when needed) then more compact expression to 
get the size ( if you really need it as I don't see the use case yet) is to use `std::count`

```
auto size = std::count(table.cbegin(),table.cend());
```

Comment: I had to make that:
auto size = std::distance(table.cbegin(),table.cend());

Comment: @MirkoLindner - it's going to be same complexity as std::count as std::distance has to iterate it can't just calculate distance because those iterators , as multi_index iterators are not random access like in std::vector where all elements are continuous. If you use std::distance on vector it's just `end - begin` pretty much . https://stackoverflow.com/a/12530248/2264070

Comment: This does not compile. std::count requires a third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find one in the documentation. But maybe you can maintain the variable yourself in the contract state:

```
Increase on add
Decrease on remove
```

If you store it in a multi_index you could use a member table which will maintain the variable.

```
ID (unint64_t) | Attribut (String) | Value (String)
0              | 'mCounter'        | '5'
```

Comment: hmm, that's obnoxious there's no `len()` or `count()` for multi-index -- thank you